# Countdown Timer that disappear after 10 minutes and not reset the counter

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a countdown timer of 10 minutes. I was wondering on how could I make the counter to stop showing up when the time is up or keep counting from the number time that there is left even after you refresh the page.

```js
// 10 minutes from now
var time_in_minutes = 10;
var current_time = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(current_time + time_in_minutes * 60 * 1000);


function time_remaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function run_clock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);

  function update_clock() {
    var t = time_remaining(endtime);
    clock.innerHTML = "<span style='color: #E89E88; font-weight: bold;'>DÉSE PRISA! </span>" + 'Use el código de descuento' + "<span style='font-weight: bold; color:white;'>'DESCUENTO5'</span>" + ' en los próximos ' + t.minutes + ' m ' + t.seconds + ' s ' + ', y ahorre un extra 5% en su pedido!';
    if (t.total == 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  update_clock(); // run function once at first to avoid delay
  var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock, 1000);
}
run_clock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
  background: #bfbfbf;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv"></div>
```

Comment: You could add a css rule to hide your element when the time has run out. You'd then need to remove that again later if you restart the counter. But that'd be a simple way of doing it.

Comment: If the environment is browser use two timers. The first cyclically writes the counter to a variable in Storage. The second periodically reads the meter reading from Storage and checks whether it has exceeded the set value. It will not be accurate but it will be independent of restarting the website.

Comment: you need to store timer info to reload it on refresh, you can use browser local storage.

Comment: How resistant to user tampering does this have to be? If the user clears local storage before reloading, the clock will start from the beginning.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help. Well It is going to be for a store website. It is a timer that shows up at the cart page, and it counts from 10 to 0 with a discount to use. So the plan it is to make it disappear onces the time is up or and not restart every time the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

try this code , you can set date you're counting down to  , if you reload page or open it in a new window

```
    <!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It help me to fixed! I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code and used [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the timer. Please follow this example:

#### HTML:

Its better to separate the HTML part to avoid re-creating it every second when using `setInterval`

```html
<div class="clockdiv">
  <span style="color: #e89e88; font-weight: bold;">DÉSE PRISA! </span> Use el código de
  descuento <span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">'DESCUENTO5'</span> en los próximos
  <span id="event_timer">loading.. </span>, y ahorre un extra 5% en su pedido!
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```js
// Span element that will hold the timer
const clock = document.getElementById("event_timer");
// Duration in minutes
const duration = 10;

function resetStartTime() {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  const eventTime = duration * 60 * 1000;
  const eventDuration = new Date(startTime + eventTime);
  // Save to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("startTime", eventDuration);
  return eventDuration;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Get the stored time
  const startTime = new Date(
    localStorage.getItem("startTime") || resetStartTime()
  );
  // Starting the timer
  timeInterval = setInterval(() => {
    // Stored value - current time
    const timer = startTime.getTime() - Date.now();

    // Uncomment these lines if you want to use 'days' and 'hours'
    // const days = Math.floor(timer / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    // const hours = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    const minutes = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((timer % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Add to DOM
    clock.innerText = minutes + " Minutes, " + seconds + " Seconds ";

    // Clear and reset when done
    if (timer <= 0) {
      clock.innerText = "EXPIRADO!";
      localStorage.removeItem("startTime");
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

---

Here is a **[codePen](https://codepen.io/awran5/pen/MWaryWZ)** example (only 1 minute) since localStorage is not supported here.

Answer (score 0):

Try [adding an event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) to determine when the timer hits 0, and use your [window's local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) property to keep track of the time that has passed even if the browser refreshes.

Comment: Hi Shemona, This should be a comment not an answer.